# Howto make Java JNI KeyListener with C++

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, global, keylistener

I'm trying to make a program like AutoHotKey, but with a graphical interface.
I'm using java.awt.Robot
Now I want to make the code for checking the state from a key (In AHK: getKeyState)
Of course somthing like a KeyListener without having focus.
I read already something with JNI and C++, but....
I can't find some information.

Can somebody help me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of good JNI resources for starting out with JNI Programming like the [Sun JNI Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jni.html). Almost all Tutorials assume a good knowledge of C/C++ because the Java Native Interface (JNI) is the bridge between native C/C++ code, the Java Virtual Machine and everything running in there (meaning your Java Bytecode).

What you may want to do first is to find a key capturing library for your operating system of choice (you didn't mention anything specific here) in C++ and try that out as well as checking if there are already some Java bindings (libraries that use JNI and offer Java classes) to interact with. I didn't find any promising on a quick search unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

works perfect for windows 32/64 Bit. It's not necessary to integrate the dll files into the (eclipse)workspace / deployment process. Amazing Lib:

Hot stuff!
http://ksquared.de/blog/2011/07/java-global-system-hook/

Comment: Maybe someone can download & test this library on mac os / linux and post behavior ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that bare links to your own website/product are not encouraged here for two reasons; First, an answer should be posted as a self-contained answer, not a mere link to an external site. Second, self-promotion tends to be frowned upon here, and often is flagged as spam (especially if there is no disclosure that you are linking to your own site/product).